# Displaying a form on clicking a file download link?

Tags: 7, forms, hooks, files

In D7, is it possible to implement the following scenario: user clicks a file link and is redirected to a generated form that must be filled before actual file download starts. File downloads are made private. I tried to use [`hook_file_download()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7) for that purpose but it obviously should be used for checking user permissions rather than displaying any forms so I'm kinda lost. How should one handle such situations? I'm looking forward to both general advice and (if possible) actual code snippets.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28810/setting-up-a-download-page-requiring-a-user-to-fill-a-form-before-downloading-an/28855#28855" In this question I provided some code, how i did it. In my case files were not private but you can get some idea.

Comment: @dkiscool Thanks, you gave me an idea. I'll update my initial post when I figure out how to bend it to my needs.